# glmulti wrapper for lmer does not produce results

Tags: r, lme4

I am using a `glmulti` wrapper for glmer (binomial) and the `summary` is:

`This is glmulti 1.0.7, Apr. 2013.
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL`

Following what has been done on this this thread, though this is for `lmer`,
[glmulti runs indefinitely when using genetic algorithm with lme4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228418/glmulti-runs-indefinitely-when-using-genetic-algorithm-with-lme4), I get the same result as above. Could it be that the versions have changed since and the wrapping has to be done differently? The following is the dummy code (lifted form the link above):

```
x = as.factor(round(runif(30),1))# dummy grouping factor
yind = runif(30,0,10) # mock dependent variable
a = runif(30) # dummy covariate
b = runif(30) # another dummy covariate
c = runif(30) # an another one
d = runif(30)

tmpdata <- data.frame(x=x,yind=yind,a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d)

lmer.glmulti <- function (formula, data, random = "", ...) {
lmer(paste(deparse(formula), random), data = data, REML=F, ...)
}

summary(glmulti(formula = yind~a*b*c*d,
                data = tmpdata,
                random = '+(1|x)',
                level = 2,
                method = 'h',
                crit = 'aicc',
                marginality = TRUE,
                fitfunc = lmer.glmulti))
```

`lme4` version: 1.1.5

`glmulti` version: 1.0.7

"R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"

**SOLUTION**

This works:

```
lmer.glmulti <- function (formula, data, random, ...) {
lmer(paste(deparse(formula), random), data = data)
}

glmulti(y = yind~a*b*c*d,
data = tmpdata,
random = '+(1|x)',
level = 2,
method = 'h',
crit = 'aicc',
marginality = TRUE,
fitfunc = lmer.glmulti)
```

packageVersion('lme4')
‘1.1.5’

packageVersion('glmulti')
‘1.0.7’

R.version: 3.1.0

**FYI:** From the package maintainer:

"fitfunc must be the name of a function so your other call including the function definition in the glmulti call cannot work."

"you named the first argument to glmulti 'formula', where it must be unnamed or 'y'... Sorry. But y is a formula (if passing a string it is the dependent variable only). "

Comment: Don't know offhand.  When I try this `glmulti` returns *immediately*, suggesting that it has decided it just can't handle this kind of model.  However, `glmulti` uses S4 dispatching, and I'm horrible at tracing S4 methods whenever it's been more than a couple of days since I tried ... I did `names(findMethods("glmulti"))` but that didn't help much. When I try the example in the linked example, I get `Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list`. At the moment I can't figure out how to trace farther, and don't have time right now  ... maybe try the pkg maintainer ?

Comment: Thanks! will check with the pkg maintainer